# How do I return a static page as a ViewResult in a global error filter (MVC4)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to write an FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter global error handling attribute which should serve up a custom error view. I override public void OnException(ExceptionContext context) and do

```
context.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
context.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;

context.ExceptionHandled = true;
context.Result = new ViewResult { ... not sure what to put here... }
```

which is where I am stuck.
Everything I have tried so far causes me to see internal server error pages. I suspect I want something like

```
context.Result = new ViewResult
{
    ViewName = "~/Errors/ReadOnlyMode.cshtml",
}
```

However that didn't seem to work (internal server errors...).

Comment: note - I don't think I want to do redirects - they shouldn't be necessary as long as I return an error status code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
context.Result = new ViewResult
{
    ViewName = "~/Views/Errors/ReadOnlyMode.cshtml",
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It (original code) should work fine. I couldn't figure out why it was not working until I removed all custom error handling sections in web.config. At which point I finally could see that there was a compile error in my .cshtml that was getting masked.

Answer (score 1):

```
context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
    new RouteValueDictionary 
    { 
        { "Controller", "Errors" }, 
        { "Action", "ReadOnlyMode" } 
    });
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: I don't think I want to do redirects - unless you have a good reason to?